# How to remove coordinates and corresponding arrays from variables that have 'nan' in xarray

Tags: dataframe, nan, netcdf, python-xarray

I have an nc file "data1.nc" that plots like this:
[image]

[image]

I performed masking over the data to remove ocean values, making a new nc file: "new.nc", in which, the ocean values are now 'nan' and it plots as following:

[image]
[image]

I want to remove the coordinates from the "new" file which now have 'nan' corresponding to the variables (r and t), all 'nan' arrays has to be removed corresponding to these coordinates also.

Answer (score 0):

Have you had any success with the [Dataset.dropna](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/generated/xarray.Dataset.dropna.html) method? I *think* you're looking at something like `dataset.dropna("lon", how="all")`, `dataset.dropna("level", how="all")`, and `dataset.dropna("time", how="all")`, but it'll take some experimentation. You should be able to experiment to your heart's content in the interpreter or an IDE (Pycharm is my favorite since it makes it easy to investigate what's currently in there), because it won't change the actual file until you run the command to do so.

If I remember correctly, though, netcdf doesn't support jagged arrays, so you might end up just being stuck with those `NaN` values simply by virtue of those coordinates needing to exist. For instance, it looks like you'll *never* be rid of any of the `lat` values since there will always be *some* value along that coordinate.